# Remove single comment by babel

Tags: babeljs

I want to remove single comment from AST. I have babel plugin where I target a node. This node has some `leadingComments`. A node would be removed using `path.remove()` but the comments would remain present. How can I remove also the comment. I don't want to remove all the comments only some particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite unintuitively, but
`Babel.types.removeComments(path.node);`
does the trick.

Comment: I'm looking at https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-types and I don't see that method anywhere. What is your source?

Comment: It was long time ago, but I guess some sort of some handbook mentioned it. Or maybe I've just scrolled through babel's code.

Comment: https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/packages/babel-types/src/comments/removeComments.js